# PowerShell raises ParentContainsErrorRecordException when calling a program with comma separated param value

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm currently trying to execute a program, that receives a Parameter which contains Elements to be included or excluded (marked with '-').

E.g. to exclude an element A and include an element B, one could call

```
.\Programm.exe /param -A,B
```

This is working well using the cmd but throws a ParserError: ParentContaintsErrorRecordException when using PowerShell.

Calling `.\Programm.exe /param B,-A` or `.\Programm.exe /param "-A,B"` works with both, Cmd and Powershell.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

When the parser sees a token in the command-line that starts with a hyphen (-), it expects that it is seeing a parameter name.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Parameters may start with a hyphen too. But why does the PowerShell even try to parse them? Afaik the only thing it does with this information is splitting the string on blanks to keep the syntax from cmd. Doing so the given/expected parameter is relevant for the called program only ...